# having problems with php syntax and foreach

Tags: php

getting an Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/maxer/domains/x/public_html/x/items.php on line 41

line 41 is the foreach

```
$items = getUserList($user,0,100);

foreach($items as $item){

    echo "<img src=\"".$item['image']."\">"; //image
    echo ""; //title
    echo ""; //button for add to list

}
```

Comment: what does `vardump($items)` say?

Comment: As an aside, one thing that's kind of nice to do when writing a function that might return an array is to make it return an empty array if there are no items found. That way, you never run into this error.

Comment: I switched to this method as well as casting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your function getUserList does not returning array
to make sure that $items is array write like this:

```
$items = (array) getUserList($user,0,100);
```

Comment: After finding solution people forgetting about this website until next issue )

Answer (score 4):

That means `$items` is not an array *or doesn't implement Traversable*. If you supply something that's not an array *and doesn't implement Traversable* to `foreach`, it'll complain with this message. Either cast the result of `getUserList` to an array or check to see if it is one.

```
$items = (array)getUserList($user,0,100);
```

or something like this:

```
$items = getUserList($user,0,100);

if (!is_array($items)) {
    // error
} else {
    foreach ($items …) {
        // …
    }
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, any value that's an array *or* implements Traversable can be used in a foreach loop.